# OLS question about standard errors and Heteroscedasticity

Tags: regression, heteroscedasticity, robust-standard-error

In the case of OLS, what stops one from modelling heteroscedasticity and providing predictor dependent coefficients. So, different ranges of the predictor with their own standard errors? Is this something that is done?

I've heard of WLS, double exponential regression? And GAMS as models that do this. Can someone break down in simple terms the difference between these